# Which Linux distro should I use for compilation

Tags: linux, compilation

Initially, I compiled my project (Qt) on Ubuntu, on distributing the deb files, some people complained, that my application failed to execute, because their OS uses libc 2.14 or even less. So, different Linux distros come with different library versions. Which Linux distro should I use for compiling, so that my application can run on all Linux distros. The problem is mainly being caused by old version of C libraries used by some stable Linux Distros.

Comment: Why not tell those users to upgrade libc?

Comment: I came to know, Ubuntu is a bleeding edge OS, and many Linux users prefer Debian or similar (stable) systems, because such systems seldom hang or crash and don't use newer libraries unless they are fully tested.

Comment: Gentoo really *likes* compilation!

Comment: Gentoo uses glibc 2.15 in stable and 2.16 in unstable version, hence not a candidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to compile your binaries against a very old version of libc, chances are that it will fail on machines running the latest version of distros, since there might not be `compat-` packages for `libc` supporting a very old version of `libc`.

On the contrary, if you try to use a very new version, it would break on older machines.

So compiling on a distro like `CentOS 6` or `Ubuntu 10.04` seems like a reasonable middle-ground to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu but maybe the earlier version (10.04 LTS). Static linking to libc is usually discouraged but running the earlier version of the machine, you can use the old libc and add apt pinning to get newer packages from later distributions.

Comment: I don't mind using some other Linux distro even if it is different than Ubuntu